# Problem when trying to validate email that already exists in database

Tags: php, validation, oop, model-view-controller

I am building custom mvc framework in php in order to learn and when I am trying to submit my form with an mail that already exists in the database, my validation should prevent me to do so, instead I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function findUserByEmail() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\gacho\App\Controllers\UsersController.php:
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Core\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($controller, $action)
    {
        parent::__construct($controller, $action);
        $this->userModel = $this->load_model('User');
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            $data = [
                'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
                ];
            }

            if (empty($data['email'])) {
                $data['email_err'] = "Please enter your email!!!";
            } else {
                if ($this->userModel->findUserByEmail($data['email'])) {
                $data['email_err'] = "Email is already taken!";
                }
          }
    }
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Core\Database;

class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function findUserByEmail($email)
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $this->db->bind(':email', $email);
        $row = $this->db->single();
        if ($this->db->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller.php:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

class Controller
{
    protected $_controller;
    protected $_action;
    public $view;

    public function __construct($controller, $action)
    {
        $this->_controller = $controller;
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    protected function load_model($model)
    {
        $modelPath = 'App\Models\\' . $model;
        if (class_exists($modelPath)) {
            $this->{$model.'Model'} = new $modelPath();
        } 
    }
}
```

I think the mistake is about $this->userModel , but I'm stuck and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in __construct of UsersController you have:

```
$this->userModel = $this->load_model('User');
```

So you assign to `userModel` property the return value of `load_model` method.
`load_model` method doesn't return anything so `$this->userModel` is always set to `NULL`, doesn't matter if `load_model` succeeded or not.

You should just `return new $modelPath();` in `load_model` if you want to assign it to a property by return value.

Also add `throw new Exception($modelPath. 'not found');` at the end of `load_model` method to be sure it did load the model, and not just failed silently to find it.

Note that `$this->userModel` is not the same as `$this->UserModel` (case sensitive) and `$modelPath = 'App\Models\\' . $model;` - why \ after App, and two \ after Models?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to access your model in $this->UserModel, since `User` was passed into the load_model method.

Comment: I tried something, but I don't think I understand exactly what you mean. Can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: Can you change $this->userModel to $this->UserModel in `UserController`

Comment: Yes. That's what I did, but it shows the same mistake.